# Why am i getting Runtime exception: fetch address not aligned on word boundary

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I had task for my schoolwork that included this code and i need to fix it but i can't continue now... The code is supposed to move one array t

```
          .data
source:   .word   3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 0
dest:     .word   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
countmsg: .asciiz " values copied. "

          .text

main:   la      $a0,source
    la      $a1,dest

loop:   lw      $v1, 0($a0)     # read next word from source
        addiu   $v0, $v0, 1     # increment count words copied
        sw      $v1, 0($a1)     # write to destination
        addiu   $a0, $a0, 1     # advance pointer to next source
        addiu   $a1, $a1, 1     # advance pointer to next dest
        bne     $v1, $zero, loop# loop if word copied not zero

loopend:
        move    $a0,$v0         # $a0 <- count
        jal     puti            # print it

        la      $a0,countmsg    # $a0 <- countmsg
        jal     puts            # print it

        li      $a0,0x0A        # $a0 <- '\n'
        jal     putc            # print it

finish:
        li      $v0, 10         # Exit the program
        syscall




### The following functions do syscalls in order to print data (integer, string, character)
#Note: argument $a0 to syscall has already been set by the CALLEE

puti:
        li      $v0, 1          # specify Print Integer service
        syscall                 # Print it
        jr      $ra             # Return

puts:
        li      $v0, 4          # specify Print String service
        syscall                 # Print it
        jr      $ra             # Return

putc:
        li      $v0, 11         # specify Print Character service
        syscall                 # Print it
        jr      $ra             # Return
```

It returns Runtime exception at 0x00400010: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x10010001

The error is on line 11 i think but i can't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `addiu   $a0, $a0, 4` as you have to jump to next word

Answer (score 0):

You are advancing pointers wrong.
If the elements of your array are words, then you have to use `lw`/`sw` to read/write elements from/to the array and take into account that each element occupies 4 bytes (thus, 1 word). So to advance the pointer you have to add 4 to the pointer (`$a0` and `$a1` in your code).

If you were trying to use an array of bytes then you'd use `.byte` directive to define your array, `lb`/`sb` and advance the pointer by increment it 1 position at a time (as you are doing in your code).